# CMake and https

Tags: https, cmake

I upgraded CMake from 2.8 to 3.2.
It seems to work, but since that I receive the error message

```
-- downloading...
     src='https://googletest.googlecode.com/files/gtest-1.7.0.zip'
     dst='... /build/gtest/src/gtest-1.7.0.zip'
     timeout='none'
CMake Error at gtest-stamp/download-gtest.cmake:21 (message):
  error: downloading
  'https://googletest.googlecode.com/files/gtest-1.7.0.zip' failed

    status_code: 1
    status_string: "Unsupported protocol"
    log: Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

  Closing connection -1
```

When I change the protocol from https to http, it runs OK. What is the reason of removing https from supported protocols?

Comment: or your curl doesn't support a recent enough ssh that google's properly refusing to use whatever outdated/insecure crypto protocols your curl DOES support.

Comment: @Marc B You are probably right. My system said I had the newest curl. I also reinstalled curl using instructions from http://devendraverma.com/install-curl-on-ubuntu-14-04/ . However, my system keeps saying the same error. Any more idea?